# Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API,

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, react-dom

how to solve this error?
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

   ```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import "./index.css";
    import { ButtonToolbar, Dropdown, DropdownButton } from "react-bootstrap";

    class Box extends React.Component {
      selectBox = () => {
        this.props.selectBox(this.props.row, this.props.col);
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div
            className={this.props.boxClass}
            id={this.props.id}
            onClick={this.selectBox}
          />
        );
      }
    }

    class Grid extends React.Component {
      render() {
        const width = this.props.cols * 14;
        var rowsArr = [];

        var boxClass = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.props.rows; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < this.props.cols; j++) {
            let boxId = i + "_" + j;

            boxClass = this.props.gridFull[i][j] ? "box on" : "box off";
            rowsArr.push(
              <Box
                boxClass={boxClass}
                key={boxId}
                boxId={boxId}
                row={i}
                col={j}
                selectBox={this.props.selectBox}
              />
            );
          }
        }

        return (
          <div className="grid" style={{ width: width }}>
            {rowsArr}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    class Buttons extends React.Component {
      handleSelect = (evt) => {
        this.props.gridSize(evt);
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="center">
            <ButtonToolbar>
              <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.props.playButton}>
                Play
              </button>
              <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.props.pauseButton}>
                Pause
              </button>
              <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.props.clear}>
                Clear
              </button>
              <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.props.slow}>
                Slow
              </button>
              <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.props.fast}>
                Fast
              </button>
              <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.props.seed}>
                Seed
              </button>
              <DropdownButton
                title="Grid Size"
                id="size-menu"
                onSelect={this.handleSelect}
              >
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">20x10</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2">50x30</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="3">70x50</Dropdown.Item>
              </DropdownButton>
            </ButtonToolbar>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    class Main extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.speed = 100;
        this.rows = 30;
        this.cols = 50;

        this.state = {
          generation: 0,
          gridFull: Array(this.rows)
            .fill()
            .map(() => Array(this.cols).fill(false)),
        };
      }

      selectBox = (row, col) => {
        let gridCopy = arrayClone(this.state.gridFull);
        gridCopy[row][col] = !gridCopy[row][col];
        this.setState({
          gridFull: gridCopy,
        });
      };

      seed = () => {
        let gridCopy = arrayClone(this.state.gridFull);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
            if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) === 1) {
              gridCopy[i][j] = true;
            }
          }
        }
        this.setState({
          gridFull: gridCopy,
        });
      };

      playButton = () => {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
        this.intervalId = setInterval(this.play, this.speed);
      };

      pauseButton = () => {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
      };

      slow = () => {
        this.speed = 1000;
        this.playButton();
      };

      fast = () => {
        this.speed = 100;
        this.playButton();
      };

      clear = () => {
        var grid = Array(this.rows)
          .fill()
          .map(() => Array(this.cols).fill(false));
        this.setState({
          gridFull: grid,
          generation: 0,
        });
      };

      gridSize = (size) => {
        switch (size) {
          case "1":
            this.cols = 20;
            this.rows = 10;
            break;
          case "2":
            this.cols = 50;
            this.rows = 30;
            break;
          default:
            this.cols = 70;
            this.rows = 50;
        }
        this.clear();
      };

      play = () => {
        let g = this.state.gridFull;
        let g2 = arrayClone(this.state.gridFull);

        for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
            let count = 0;
            if (i > 0) if (g[i - 1][j]) count++;
            if (i > 0 && j > 0) if (g[i - 1][j - 1]) count++;
            if (i > 0 && j < this.cols - 1) if (g[i - 1][j + 1]) count++;
            if (j < this.cols - 1) if (g[i][j + 1]) count++;
            if (j > 0) if (g[i][j - 1]) count++;
            if (i < this.rows - 1) if (g[i + 1][j]) count++;
            if (i < this.rows - 1 && j > 0) if (g[i + 1][j - 1]) count++;
            if (i < this.rows - 1 && j < this.cols - 1)
              if (g[i + 1][j + 1]) count++;
            if (g[i][j] && (count < 2 || count > 3)) g2[i][j] = false;
            if (!g[i][j] && count === 3) g2[i][j] = true;
          }
        }
        this.setState({
          gridFull: g2,
          generation: this.state.generation + 1,
        });
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        this.seed();
        this.playButton();
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>The Game of Life</h1>
            <Buttons
              playButton={this.playButton}
              pauseButton={this.pauseButton}
              slow={this.slow}
              fast={this.fast}
              clear={this.clear}
              seed={this.seed}
              gridSize={this.gridSize}
            />
            <Grid
              gridFull={this.state.gridFull}
              rows={this.rows}
              cols={this.cols}
              selectBox={this.selectBox}
            />
            <h2>Generations: {this.state.generation}</h2>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    function arrayClone(arr) {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
   ```

Comment: In React version 18 they changed where and how in import ReactDOM. What version of react are you using see your package.json. How are you importing ReactDom?

Comment: i am using react version 18.but i know about react version 17 library.how to change the code so that it works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.